# Python Requests - Use TLS v.1_3

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests

I am trying to make a request in Python using TLS 1.3 as it is what the site accepts.
I use following code:

```
import requests
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from requests.packages.urllib3.poolmanager import PoolManager
from requests.packages.urllib3.util import ssl_

CIPHERS = (
    'AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA'
)


class TlsAdapter(HTTPAdapter):

    def __init__(self, ssl_options=0, **kwargs):
        self.ssl_options = ssl_options
        super(TlsAdapter, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def init_poolmanager(self, *pool_args, **pool_kwargs):
        ctx = ssl_.create_urllib3_context(ciphers=CIPHERS, cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED, options=self.ssl_options)
        self.poolmanager = PoolManager(*pool_args,
                                       ssl_context=ctx,
                                       **pool_kwargs)


sess = requests.session()
adp = TlsAdapter(ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1_3 | ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1_3)
sess.mount("https://", adapter)
```

Everything looks fine until here. I started using it to send requests ecc but of pure curiosity I checked deeper and used Wireshark. Here it says the requests go over 1.2 and not 1.3.

Anyone could help me actually to enforce 1.3 and not 1.2? It would be very appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: 1) Do not set ciphers, just say you want TLS 1.3 and 2) "and used Wireshark. Here it says the requests go over 1.2 and not 1.3. " this is complicated (and hence imprecise in your question) as 1.3 was **designed** to look like as 1.2 in some spots (some parts of the messages exchanged) to be able to bypass stupid middleboxes (is that a pleonasm?). See for example "protocolVersion legacy_record_version = 0x0303;  /* TLS v1.2 */" in RFC 8446.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I was just about to link to [your older answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52081241/4756299)...  :-)

Comment: `ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1_3 | ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1_3` is strange on two counts. First there is an extra unneeded one as "A OR A" is always A, and second `OP_NO_TLSv1_3` specifically **prevents** doing TLS 1.3, see https://docs.python.org/2/library/ssl.html#ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1_3 : "Prevents a TLSv1.3 connection. This option is only applicable in conjunction with PROTOCOL_TLS. It prevents the peers from choosing TLSv1.3 as the protocol version."

Comment: @AndrewHenle Thanks :-) I forgot I wrote that, but it can fit indeed.

Comment: ok thanks a lot for this info. any chance how I can set it to TLS 1.3 without that or ?

Comment: Either use `PROTOCOL_TLS` that will auto-negotiate highest possible version (better for upward compatibility) or if you insist on 1.3 and that only, `OP_NO_SSLv2 & OP_NO_SSLv3 & OP_NO_TLSv1 & OP_NO_TLSv1_1 & OP_NO_TLSv1_2` should prevent all of these protocols and hence it remains (today) either 1.3 or nothing at all (depending on underlying OpenSSL version and what the remote server accepts)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your made a typo on the last line. Use this instead.

```
sess = requests.session()
adp = TlsAdapter(ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1_3 | ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1_3)
sess.mount("https://", adp) #adp instead of adapter
```