# Pickle a python requests session to implement "TLS session resumption" across different application runs

Tags: ssl, python-requests, tls1.2

I'm trying to implement TLS session resumption for my command line application.

This issue [#2522](https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/2522) explains how to pickle a `requests.session`.

However, the TLS handshake is repeated when I rerun my application (loading a pickled session).

I was wondering what am I missing? Is this even possible?

The behavior I want is:

```sh
# first execution, TLS handshake is performed
$ time my_python_app.py
0.2s

# second execution, TLS handshake is reused
$ time my_python_app.py
0.02s
```

Answer (score 1):

This is likely not possible with the API provided by the ssl libraries form Python (i.e `ssl` or `pyopenssl`). In OpenSSL the TLS session is a memory structure which has pointers to other structures etc - and this structure would need to be somehow serialized for storing and unserialized later in a different process. There are the functions i2d_SSL_SESSION and d2i_SSL_SESSION to do this but these and all the other functions needed to recreate a session into a context are not exposed to Python.

If possible use TLS 1.3 instead. It already has a shortened TLS handshake even without session reuse.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time. I saw this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57599480/python-requests-use-tls-v-1-3
however it does not improve performance. 

Do you have an idea how I could get requests to use TLS 1.3?

Comment: @jsmedmar: There is nothing you explicitly need to do in your code. It will automatically use TLS 1.3 if a) Python is compiled with OpenSSL 1.1.1 and b) the server does support TLS 1.3 too.

Comment: Thanks Steffen. I went on to ensure that TLS 1.3 with 0-RTT is supported by my server (see https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=cornell.isabl.io&hideResults=on), however I did not see any improvement in performance when using curl or python. It seems that for whatever reason 0-RTT is not being used... Any clues how to debug?

Comment: When I check the security tab in the browser, it shows it's successfully using TLS 1.3, however the TLS Setup timing is still >50ms